# Laravel Select2 default value

Tags: php, jquery-select2

I am using select2 for selection of users, I am populating select2 according to its value in database, I am doing it like this :

```
<input class="form-control" data-tag-select="director" remote-url="{{ route("query::applies")}}" name="agency_director" type="hidden" value="{{ $team->name }}">
```

In the `value` simply i am adding the variable `{{ $team->name }}` which have the value but nothing comes up.

What am i missing ?

Comment: What version of Select2 are you using? The `<input>` style is deprecated in favor of the `<select>` element in versions after 2.4: https://select2.github.io/options.html#input-fallback

Comment: i don't which version am i using, but its old.

Comment: Perhaps the older version does not support the default value the way you are doing it? My suggestion would be to upgrade to the latest and greatest if possible.

Comment: @jeremyHarris I am using 3.5.1...